# Android Pay - Programatically click on "Buy Now" button

Tags: android, onclick, fragment, android-pay

Is there a way to programmatically click the "Buy with Android Pay" button on Android? I can't find a way to do it as that button is rendered inside SupportWalletFragment.

[This guide](https://android-pay-toolkit.appspot.com/in-android-applications/) seems to show it is possible.

Comment: The button is in a fragment and you want to access it from an another fragment/activity?

Comment: I just want to programmatically start the Android Pay flow (ie, the pop-up that shows up when you tap on the Android Pay button). That fragment does not contain any "startPaymentFlow()" method so I guess the only way is to get a reference for the button somehow and calling "performClick()" on it.

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: I skimmed the tutorial and didn't see anything about programmatically clicking the button.  Where do you think you saw that?  I suspect you misunderstood, because clicking a payment button on behalf of the user would generally be a really, really, really bad idea, and not something Google would encourage in the slightest.  Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: @nasch My screen has some radio buttons. The first Radio Button contains the Android Pay option and is selected by default. The second radio button contains an option to pay by credit card directly, etc. The user can both click on the Android Pay button directly or select the radio button and click on the "Continue" button we have at the bottom of the screen. This last case is why I want to start the Android Pay flow programmatically as the user would by tapping on my Continue button, not on the Android Pay button.

Comment: @nasch I agree this would be a security concern IF tapping on the Android Pay button would be the last action needed for the user to complete the purchase. In practice, however, the user is taken to the Order Confirmation page and then he needs to confirm the order. It is not like the Facebook "Like" button that does not take you anywhere and that is why Facebook does not allow you to "Like" something programmatically. Moreover, starting the payment flow is possible in Apple Pay, but it looks like it is not possible on Android Pay =(

Comment: I doubt the button is exposed to you. Can you just have to buttons instead of radio buttons and a button?

Comment: @nasch That's how it is now, but it looks weird having only the Android Pay button without a radio button next to it (like the other payment options in my app have). I will leave the question opened even though I believe there is no solution to this.

Comment: My suggestion is not to use radio buttons at all, just buttons.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can actually programmatically perform a click for SupportWalletFragment, but you can programmatically start Android Pay flow using the following method:

```
Wallet.Payments.loadMaskedWallet(googleApiClient, maskedWalletRequest, requestCode);
```

Details about Payments API:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/Payments.html#top_of_page